# How can I "recursively" stringify a javascript function which calls other scoped functions?

Tags: javascript, recursion, serialization, tostring

Because javascript functions are not serializable, in order to pass them into new contexts sometimes (albeit rarely) it can be useful to stringify them then re-evaluate them later like:

```
const foo = () => { // do something }
const fooText = foo.toString()

// later... in new context & scope
const fooFunc = new Function(' return (' + fooText + ').apply(null, arguments)')
fooFunc() // works!
```

However, if `foo` references another function `bar`, the scope is not stringified, **so if `bar` is not defined in the new context, the evaluated foo function will throw an error when called.**

### I'm wondering if there is a way to stringify a function recursively?

That is, not only stringifying the parent function, but also stringifying the contents of the child functions called from the parent.

#### For Example:

```
let bar = () => { alert(1) }
let foo = () => { bar() }

// what toString does
let fooString = foo.toString()
console.log(fooString) // "() => { bar() }"

// what we want
let recursiveFooString = foo.recursiveToString()
console.log(recursiveFooString) // "() => { alert(1) }"
```

Let me know if you have any ideas on how to accomplish something like a "recursiveToString"

Comment: Doing a recursive eval call is very inefficient, while also quite difficult to do (though not impossible). I'm interested on the why you need to do that. Perhaps there is another way to achieve your bigger goal, that doesn't include serializing.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant You can use a parser or AST converter to get all of the parameters and functions used inside the original function. You can then use `eval` to convert those function to string (needs to be in the same scope).

Comment: @nickzoum Yes, but I said that you can't copy the scope itself (unless ofcourse copy everything within the scope, as in CertainPerformance's answer).

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant You can't copy the scope itself but you can use `eval(\`${internalFunction}.toString()\`)` recursively whenever you find a function that wasn't defined inside the original scope.

Comment: @nickzoum Umm ... yeah, though that way the nested scopes would be flattened to a single scope, but that doesn't actually make any difference.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Why doesn't it make a difference? It essentially serializes the function and any external function used inside that function. The only problem is that this cannot be implemented using a function, you need to implement this code in the scope you need.

Comment: @nickzoum Yes, I meant that the flattened construction doesn't matter, a flat scope will do as well, unless there are naming conflicts. But the interesting question is why ... I could imagine storing a function in JSON as text and then use that on somewhere else in the code, or even in a totally different code. Otherwise a reference should do as well.

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant Oh, yes I've already asked OP to answer why this method is required and what the original problem is since this sounds like an XY problem

Comment: The end goal is to build a completely obfuscated function which calls on other functions. If you pass in one function into `javascript-obfuscator` it still references the callee by name. In order to get a completely obfuscated function, you'd need to flatten the scope somehow. CertainPerformance's answer accomplishes this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up rolling with was inspired by @CertainPerformance's answer.

**The trick is to build a function which defines all the child callee functions.** Then you have everything you need to stringify the parent function.

**Note:** to allow for imported callee functions from other files, I decided to programmatically build a string with the callee definitions rather than defining them originally in the same scope.

## The code:

```js
    // original function definitions (could be in another file)
    let bar = () => { alert(1) }
    let foo = () => { bar() }


    const allCallees = [ bar, foo ] 

    // build string of callee definitions
    const calleeDefinitions = allCallees.reduce(
      (definitionsString, callee) => {
        return `${definitionsString} \n const ${callee.name} = ${callee.toString()};`;
      }, 
      "",
    );

    // wrap the definitions in a function that calls foo
    const fooString = `() => { ${calleeDefinitions} \n return foo(); \n }`;

    console.log(fooString);
    /** 
     * fooString looks like this:
     * `() => {  
     *    const bar = () => { alert(1) }; 
     *    const foo = () => { bar() }; 
     *    return foo();
     *  }`
    **/ 
     

    // in new context & scope
    const evaluatedFoo = new Function(' return (' + fooString + ').apply(null, arguments)');

    // works as expected
    evaluatedFoo();
```

Comment: Note, though, the problem described in my answer.  This does not make it go away.  But perhaps more important is the notion that you need to do this at the time of code creation.  Given that, why not just have the serialized string handy?  Why generate it at all from code that you're currently writing?

Comment: I probably will keep the serialized (and minified) string handy rather than dynamically generating it at runtime, but say I made a change to a number of callee functions (which are stored in various files) I will want to be able to get the newly modified string easily, which is what I'll use this code for. To your point, I agree this isn't a general solution and won't account for the edge case you described, I'm going to have to write the functions such that they don't depend on free variables.

Answer (score 3):

The only *good* way to do this is to start from a parent scope that encloses all functions `foo` eventually references. For example, with your `foo` and `bar`, if you want to pass `foo` into another context such that `bar` is callable as well, pass a function that declares both `foo` and `bar`, and returns `foo`. For example:

```js
const makeFoo = () => {
  let bar = () => { alert(1) }
  let foo = () => { bar() }
  return foo;
};
const makeFooStr = makeFoo.toString();

// ...

const makeFooFunc = new Function(' return (' + makeFooStr + ').apply(null, arguments)');
const foo = makeFooFunc();
foo();
```

Implementing this sort of thing well *does* require premeditated design like above (unfortunately). You can't really include all ancestor LexicalEnvironments (the internal map of variable names to values in a given scope) when stringifying.

Comment: Thank you for the response! A wrapper function which defines all the callees in one scope definitely would get the job done. I'm wondering though if there is a way to accomplish this while still defining functions in different files (for modularity). Looking for some kind of programmatic redefine method.

Comment: ^ I suppose you could accomplish this using the same pattern, but just building the "makeFoo" function as a string from the start (using the parent scope to stringify the callees).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to stringify a function recursively?

I think we can fairly simply demonstrate that this is impossible in general.

Let's think about these two function

```js
const greet = (greeting) => (name) => `${greeting} ${name}`
const sayHi = greet ('Hi') 

sayHi ('Jane') //=> "Hi Jane"
```

While with your `foo` and `bar` example, we could possibly imagine something that examined the body of the function and used everything available in the current scope to do your extended stringify function based on parsing the function and knowing what local variables are actually used.  (I'm guessing that this would be impossible too, for reasons related to [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), but we can certainly imagine it.)

But here, note that

```js
sayHi.toString() //=> "(name) => `${greeting} ${name}`"
```

and so `sayHi` depends on a free variable *that's not stored in our current scope,* namely, `greeting`.  We simply have not stored the "Hi" used to create that function *anywhere* except in the closure scope of `sayHi`, which is not exposed anywhere.

So even this simple function could not be reliably serialized; there seems little hope for anything more complex.